# Categories in which finite powers commute with filtered colimits

Tags: ct.category-theory, locally-presentable-categories, cartesian-closed-categories

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with finite products and filtered colimits, then we say that finite powers commute with filtered colimits in $\mathcal{C}$ if for each natural number $n$, the $n$th power endofunctor $(-)^n : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ preserves filtered colimits. It is well known that if $\mathcal{C}$ is cartesian closed or locally finitely presentable, then finite powers commute with filtered colimits in $\mathcal{C}$. However, there are at least some examples of categories that are neither cartesian closed nor locally finitely presentable, but in which finite powers still commute with filtered colimits. For example, it is shown in Section 2 of Rosicky's recent paper "Metric monads" that finite powers commute with filtered colimits in the categories of (extended) metric and pseudo-metric spaces, even though neither category is cartesian closed or locally finitely presentable (although at least the former is locally countably presentable).

My question is: are there other (general classes of) examples of categories that are neither cartesian closed nor locally finitely presentable, but wherein finite powers still commute with filtered colimits (or even just colimits of countable chains)?

Comment: This is not that much weaker than the ones you suggest, but let me point out that because filtered categories are also *sifted*, it suffices that $X\times -$ commutes with filtered colimits (rather than all colimits, as "closed" seems to suggest)

Comment: Any [continuous category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/continuous+category) or [algebraically exact category](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0106) will have this property. I don't actually know an example which is not locally finitely-presentable, but perhaps the literature there might contain examples. Any finitely accessible category with finite powers will have this property. E.g. the category of [Kan complexes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+complex) or more generally the fibrant objets in an $\aleph_0$-cofibrantly-generated model structure. (But maybe you prefer co/complete examples?)

Comment: Er -- rather, Kan complexes form a cartesian closed category. But other model-category-flavored examples will work. For instance, the category of divisible abelian groups. For that matter, any additive category with filtered colimits has this property.